# Thread concurrency - Using a string object's lock for synchronisation

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, concurrency

```
class ZiggyTest{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        RunnableThread rt = new RunnableThread();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(rt);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(rt);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(rt);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.setPriority(10);
        t3.start();

        try{
            t3.join();
            t2.join();
            t1.join();

            System.out.println("Joined");
        }catch(InterruptedException e){System.out.println(e);}


        Thread t4 = new Thread(new RunnableThread());
        Thread t5 = new Thread(new RunnableThread());
        Thread t6 = new Thread(new RunnableThread());

        t4.start();
        t5.start();
        t6.start();
    }

}
```

The above test produces the following output

```
Thread-0
Thread-0
Thread-0
Thread-0
Thread-0
Thread-2
Thread-2
Thread-2
Thread-2
Thread-2
Thread-1
Thread-1
Thread-1
Thread-1
Thread-1
Joined
Thread-3
Thread-3
Thread-4
Thread-4
Thread-3
Thread-4
Thread-5
Thread-4
Thread-3
Thread-4
Thread-5
Thread-3
Thread-5
Thread-5
Thread-5
```

I don't understand why the last three threads are not using the String object as a shared lock like the first three threads. Even though the last three threads are using a different instance of 'RunnableThread', shouldn't they be synchronized because there is only one copy for 'str' in the string constant pool?

Thanks

### Edit

oops.. i forgot to include RunnableThread.

```
class RunnableThread implements Runnable{

    String str = "HELLO";

    public void run(){
        runMe();
    }

    public synchronized void runMe(){
        for (int a : new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The source for `RunnableThread` would be necessary for us to answer this question!

Comment: locking on strings? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I would not do that in real life but its a question that can show up in a real life certification exam :)

Comment: Why was the question down voted? (Scratching head..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your threads are not synchronized on any `String` object, let alone the same one, so I'm not sure where that idea comes from. They're synchronized on the `RunnableThread` object itself due to the `synchronized` keyword in this line:

```
public synchronized void runMe(){
```

Using separate `RunnableThread` objects for the last three threads means they run independently.

Now, if you actually wanted to lock on that global `String` object, the method would look like

```
public void runMe(){
    synchronized (str) {
        for (int a : new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

and it would be a good idea to make `str` `final`.

Comment: Yes it looks like that is the mistake i made. I modified it to synchronise on str and it is now working as expected. Thanks.

Comment: using a string literal or cache numbers is generally considered a bad idea.  If you want to use a shared lock, you can use `synchronized(getClass())`